# Validacion campo input text - Solo debe aceptar numeros - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Un campo `input` en un formulario:

```
<td align=right>Cod.Postal:</td><td align=left><input type="text" name="codigo" id="idcodigo" maxlength="5"></td>
```

Se debe poder escribir únicamente números (0-9).

```
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    miformulario.codigo.addEventListener("keypress", function(){ 
        return soloNumeros(event);
        }, false);
    });

    //Solo permite introducir números.
    function soloNumeros(e){
    var key = window.event ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (key < 48 || key > 57) {
        //Usando la definición del DOM level 2, "return" NO funciona.
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

**Función ValidarCP:**

```
//Validar el CP.
function validarCP(){
    //Eliminamos la clase error asignada al elemento CP.
    document.getElementById("idcodigo").className="";
    var valor = document.getElementById("idcodigo").value;
    var patron = /^\d{5}$/;
    if (patron.test(document.getElementById("idcodigo").value) && (!isNaN(valor))){
        document.getElementById("idcodigo").className="correcto";   
        return true;
    }else{
        //Situamos el foco en el campo idcodigo y le asignamos la clase error.
        alert("El código debe tener al menos 5 digitos.\n");
        document.getElementById("idcodigo").focus();
        document.getElementById("idcodigo").className="error";  
        return false;
    }
}
```

**¿Cómo asignaría esta función ValidarCP al campo "codigo"? ¿Con el evento onblur?** Quisiera que al perder el foco, compruebe si hay 5 digitos, si los hay que no pase nada, si no hay 5 digitos, que muestre un mensaje (alert()) y que ponga el fondo del campo en rojo.

styles.css

```
.error{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usando la definición del [DOM level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/) el `return` no funciona como esperas. Debes usar [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) en su lugar.

Por último, la condición debe ser la contraria a la que habías planteado:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  miformulario.codigo.addEventListener("keypress", soloNumeros, false);
});

//Solo permite introducir numeros.
function soloNumeros(e){
  var key = window.event ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if (key < 48 || key > 57) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="miformulario">
  <td align=right>Cod.Postal:</td><td align=left><input type="text" name="codigo" id="idcodigo" maxlength="5"></td>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

Lo que ocurre es que tienes que hacer la validación por el input en JavaScript, aunque le regreses un false, este no sabe qué hacer, hay que agregarle el `e.preventDefault()` para que ahora si no permita escribir caracteres que no sean de tipo número

```js
miFormulario = document.querySelector('#miFormulario');
miFormulario.codigo.addEventListener('keypress', function (e){
 if (!soloNumeros(event)){
   e.preventDefault();
  }
})

//Solo permite introducir numeros.
function soloNumeros(e){
    var key = e.charCode;
    console.log(key);
    return key >= 48 && key <= 57;
}
```

```html
<form name='miFormulario' id='miFormulario'>
<input type="text" name="codigo" id="idcodigo" maxlength="5">
</form>
```

Tomé tu código, quité algunas cosas que estaban demás, y agregué la validación de `preventDefault()`

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer solamente con html, crea tu input de tipo number. Algo como esto:

> input type="number" name="codigo"  id="idcodigo" min="0" max="9"

Comment: Sí, eso sí lo tenía en mente pero no quiero manipular el .html, lo quisiera hacer todo mediante un archivo javascript .js

Answer (score 0):

Aquí os dejo algo mas simple. Un Saludo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>SOLO NUMEROS SIMPLE</h1>
  <div>
    <input type="input" name="ESP" onKeypress="if (event.keyCode < 45 || event.keyCode > 57) event.returnValue = false;">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```