# Validación Javascript DNI - Validar tecla a tecla el campo DNI

Tags: javascript, eventos, dom

Dispongo de un formulario HTML donde un input es **DNI**. En el DNI quiero validar que se escriban sólo números y letras, además que contenta una expresión regular que sea 8dígitos junto con una letra (la letra se coloque en mayúsculas mediante .toUpperCase()).

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="DNI" maxlength="9" tabindex="4" class="input-2" onkeypress="return soloLetrasNumeros(event);">
```

**La idea es que en el campo DNI de tipo "input" se validen dos comprobaciones: que cada tecla pulsada, con el evento onKeyPress() sea solamente un número o una letra, y que al perder el foco el campo o cuando sea pulsado el botón "Enviar formulario" se compruebe si realmente contiene 8 dígitos y una letra, otra opción sería que con el método "onChange" comprobar cuando es correcto (poner el fondo verde del campo) o si es incorrecto (poner el fondo de color rojo).**

¿Sería posible realizar la idea que tengo en dos funciones o habría que englobarlo en una?

```
  function validar_formulario(){
    var nombre, apellidos, email, dni, telefono, password1, password2;
    var expresion;

    nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    apellidos = document.getElementById("apellidos").value;
    email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    dni = document.getElementById("dni").value;
    telefono = document.getElementById("telefono").value;
    password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
    password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;

    expresion = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$/;

    if(nombre=="" || apellidos=="" || email=="" || dni=="" || telefono=="" || password1=="" || password2==""){
        alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios.");
        return false;
    }else if(nombre.length>20){
        alert("El nombre debe tener menos de 21 carácteres.");
        document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
        return false;
    }else if(apellidos.length>50){
        alert("Los apellidos superan los 50 carácteres de límite.");
        document.getElementById("apellidos").focus();
        return false;
    }else if(!expresion.test(email)){
        alert("El formato del email es incorrecto.");
        document.getElementById("email").value = "";
        document.getElementById("email").focus();
        return false;
    }else if(email.length>50){
        alert("El email debe tener menos de 51 carácteres.");
        document.getElementById("email").value = "";
        document.getElementById("email").focus();
        return false;
    }else if(dni.length!=9){
        alert("El DNI debe tener exactamente 9 carácteres.");
        document.getElementById("dni").value = "";
        document.getElementById("dni").focus();
        return false;
    }else if(telefono.length!=9){
        alert("El teléfono debe tener exactamente 9 carácteres.");
        document.getElementById("telefono").value = "";
        document.getElementById("telefono").focus();
        return false;
    }else if(isNaN(telefono)){
        alert("El teléfono debe contener únicamente dígitos.");
        document.getElementById("telefono").value = "";
        document.getElementById("telefono").focus();
        return false;
    }else if(password1 != password2){
        alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden.");
        document.getElementById("password1").value = "";
        document.getElementById("password2").value = "";
        document.getElementById("password1").focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

```js
function validar_formulario(){
 var nombre, apellidos, email, dni, telefono, password1, password2;
 var expresion;
 
 nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
 apellidos = document.getElementById("apellidos").value;
 email = document.getElementById("email").value;
 dni = document.getElementById("dni").value;
 telefono = document.getElementById("telefono").value;
 password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
 password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
 
 expresion = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
 
 if(nombre=="" || apellidos=="" || email=="" || dni=="" || telefono=="" || password1=="" || password2==""){
  alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios.");
  return false;
 }else if(nombre.length>20){
  alert("El nombre debe tener menos de 21 carácteres.");
  document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
  return false;
 }else if(apellidos.length>50){
  alert("Los apellidos superan los 50 carácteres de límite.");
  document.getElementById("apellidos").focus();
  return false;
 }else if(!expresion.test(email)){
  alert("El formato del email es incorrecto.");
  document.getElementById("email").value = "";
  document.getElementById("email").focus();
  return false;
 }else if(email.length>50){
  alert("El email debe tener menos de 51 carácteres.");
  document.getElementById("email").value = "";
  document.getElementById("email").focus();
  return false;
 }else if(dni.length!=9){
  alert("El DNI debe tener exactamente 9 carácteres.");
  document.getElementById("dni").value = "";
  document.getElementById("dni").focus();
  return false;
 }else if(telefono.length!=9){
  alert("El teléfono debe tener exactamente 9 carácteres.");
  document.getElementById("telefono").value = "";
  document.getElementById("telefono").focus();
  return false;
 }else if(isNaN(telefono)){
  alert("El teléfono debe contener únicamente dígitos.");
  document.getElementById("telefono").value = "";
  document.getElementById("telefono").focus();
  return false;
 }else if(password1 != password2){
  alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden.");
  document.getElementById("password1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("password2").value = "";
  document.getElementById("password1").focus();
  return false;
 }
}


function soloLetrasNumeros(e){
 var tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    //Permitimos el acceso a una tecla "Retroceso".  <--
    if (tecla == 8){
        return true;
    }
 //Patrón de entrada: solo aceptamos números.
    var patron = /[0-9A-Za-z]/;
    var tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(tecla_final);
}
```

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 margin: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 background: #DEDEDE;
}

h1{
 margin-top: 100px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}

.form-register{
 width: 95%;
 max-width: 490px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 150px;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 7px;
}

.form-titulo{
 background: green;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-top-left-radius: 7px;
 border-top-right-radius: 7px;
 border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}

.contenedor-inputs{
 padding: 2px 20px;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

input{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 4px;
 font-size: 12px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

label{
 font-size: 16px;
}



.input-1{
 width: 98%;
}

.input-2{
 width: 48%;
}

.registrar{
 background: crimson;
 color: #fff;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 10px 40px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.registrar:active{
 transform: scale(1.05);
}

.form-link{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 7px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.footer{
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 150px;
 height: 40px;
 padding:5px 0px;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Formulario de Registro</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos_registrar.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="validar_formulario.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!--<h1>Formulario de Registro</h1>-->
  <form name="miformulario" id="miformulario" action="registrar.php" method="POST" class="form-register" onsubmit="return validar_formulario();">
   <h2 class="form-titulo">CREA UNA CUENTA</h2>
   <div class="contenedor-inputs">
    <!-- Por cada etiqueta de <input> <label for="id_mismo_que_input">XXXX: </label> -->
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" tabindex="1" class="input-2" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event);"> <!-- required para HTML5 -->
    <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" tabindex="2" class="input-2">
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" tabindex="3" class="input-1">
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="DNI" maxlength="9" tabindex="4" class="input-2" onkeypress="return soloLetrasNumeros(event);">
    <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" maxlength="9" tabindex="5" class="input-2" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event);">
    <br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password1" placeholder="Contraseña" tabindex="6" class="input-2">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password2" placeholder="Repetir contraseña" tabindex="7" class="input-2">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Registrar" name="registrar" class="registrar" tabindex="8"/>
    <?php
     include "Clases/BD.php";
     //Si pulsamos el botón insertar...
     if(isset($_POST["registrar"])){
      $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
      $apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
      $dni = $_POST["dni"];
      $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
      $email = $_POST["email"];
      $password = $_POST["password"];
      //Llamamos al método "insertarCliente" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
      BD::insertarCliente($email, $nombre, $apellidos, $dni, $telefono, $password);
     }
    ?>
    <p class="form-link">¿Ya tienes una cuenta? <a href="iniciar_sesion.php">Ingresa aquí</a></p>
   </div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70351/validacion-campo-input-text-solo-debe-aceptar-numeros-javascript) se trata el tema de solo dejar numeros. Puedes usarlo para orientarte y dejar tambien letras. Un saludo

Comment: Por otro lado, hay algo ilógico en la pregunta. Si alguien respondiera literalmente a tu pregunta, el resultado sería que muestre una alerta para cada una de las 8 teclas que presiona el usuario antes de tener un DNI de 9 caracteres correcto... ¿Cómo es eso de validar mientras escribe? ¿La validación no es después de que terminó de escribir y se va el foco del input, o intenta enviar el formulario? ... ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta con más detalle de cuál es el comportamiento esperado, paso a paso?

Comment: Creo que la pregunta está bien propuesta. La idea es que en el campo DNI de tipo "<input>" se validen dos comprobaciones: que cada tecla pulsada, con el evento onKeyPress() sea solamente un número o una letra, y que al perder el foco el campo o cuando sea pulsado el botón "Enviar formulario" se compruebe si realmente contiene 8 dígitos y una letra.

Answer (score 3):

De hecho, deberías hacerlo así, crear dos funciones:

- Una para validar el DNI (una vez completo)
- Otra para validar el digito que se introduce en el onkeypress

**Opcion A**

En el onkeypress la función para que solo se metan letras y números y una función onchange para cuando termines de escribir el dni y pierdas el foco del input, se active.

**Opcion B**

Crear una sola función que se llame validación y que se active en cada onKeyPress, dicha función primero comprueba que sea letra mayúscula o numero y despues cuenta el numero de digitos que tiene el input, si es igual a 8 significa que se ha introducido el DNI completo, con lo cual no te deja ecribir mas y automáticamente te valida el DNI (resto de la funcion).

Comment: Hola Cobas, esto no responde a la pregunta. Si es una guia pero no es la explicacion necesaria para responder. Mira [answer] para mejorarla. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Alguna posible ayuda o propuesta más visible con un ejemplo de código?

Answer (score 0):

Si solo quieres validar DNI, 8 números + 1 letra, podrías usar un patrón similar a este

```
/[0-9]{8}[A-Z]?/g
```

Con esto, te aseguras que no puedan meterte letras en medio del DNI.

Yo personalmente, prefiero validar en el evento OnBlur, usando esta función, que admite también NIE y NIF

```
function valida_nif_cif_nie(a) {
    var resul = true;
    var temp = a.toUpperCase();
    var cadenadni = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
    if (temp !== '') {
        //algoritmo para comprobacion de codigos tipo CIF
        suma = parseInt(temp.charAt(2)) + parseInt(temp.charAt(4)) + parseInt(temp.charAt(6));
        for (i = 1; i < 8; i += 2) {
            temp1 = 2 * parseInt(temp.charAt(i));
            temp1 += '';
            temp1 = temp1.substring(0,1);
            temp2 = 2 * parseInt(temp.charAt(i));
            temp2 += '';
            temp2 = temp2.substring(1,2);
            if (temp2 == '') {
                temp2 = '0';
            }
            suma += (parseInt(temp1) + parseInt(temp2));
        }
        suma += '';
        n = 10 - parseInt(suma.substring(suma.length-1, suma.length));
        //si no tiene un formato valido devuelve error
        if ((!/^[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{7}[A-Z0-9]{1}$/.test(temp) && !/^[T]{1}[A-Z0-9]{8}$/.test(temp)) && !/^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]{1}$/.test(temp)) {
            if ((temp.length == 9) && (/^[0-9]{9}$/.test(temp))) {
                var posicion = temp.substring(8,0) % 23;
                var letra = cadenadni.charAt(posicion);
                var letradni = temp.charAt(8);
                resul = false;
            } else if (temp.length == 8) {
                if (/^[0-9]{1}/.test(temp)) {
                    var posicion = temp.substring(8,0) % 23;
                    var letra = cadenadni.charAt(posicion);
                    var tipo = 'NIF';
                } else if (/^[KLM]{1}/.test(temp)) {
                    var letra = String.fromCharCode(64 + n);
                    var tipo = 'NIF';
                } else if (/^[ABCDEFGHJNPQRSUVW]{1}/.test(temp)) {
                    var letra = String.fromCharCode(64 + n);
                    var tipo = 'CIF';
                } else if (/^[T]{1}/.test(temp)) {
                    var letra = String.fromCharCode(64 + n);
                    var tipo = 'NIE';
                } else if (/^[XYZ]{1}/.test(temp)) {
                    var pos = str_replace(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['0','1','2'], temp).substring(0, 8) % 23;
                    var letra = cadenadni.substring(pos, pos + 1);
                    var tipo = 'NIE';
                }
                if (letra !== '') {
                } else {
                }
                resul = false;
            } else if (temp.length < 8) {
                resul = false;
            } else {
                resul = false;
            }
        }
        //comprobacion de NIFs estandar
        else if (/^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]{1}$/.test(temp)) {
            var posicion = temp.substring(8,0) % 23;
            var letra = cadenadni.charAt(posicion);
            var letradni = temp.charAt(8);
            if (letra == letradni) {
                resul = true;
            } else if (letra != letradni) {
                resul = false;
            } else {
                resul = false;
            }

        }
        //comprobacion de NIFs especiales (se calculan como CIFs)
        else if (/^[KLM]{1}/.test(temp)) {
            if (temp[8] == String.fromCharCode(64 + n)) {
               resul = true;
            } else if (temp[8] != String.fromCharCode(64 + n)) {
                resul = false;
            } else {
                resul = false;
            }
        }
        //comprobacion de CIFs
        else if (/^[ABCDEFGHJNPQRSUVW]{1}/.test(temp)) {
            var temp_n = n + '';
            var letra=parseInt(temp_n.substring(temp_n.length-1, temp_n.length));
            var letra2= String.fromCharCode(64 + n);
            //alert (letra);
            //alert (letra2);
            if (temp.charAt(8) ==  letra2 || temp.charAt(8) == letra) {
                resul = true;
            } else if (temp.charAt(8) != letra2) {
                 resul = false;
            } else if (temp.charAt(8) != letra) {
                 resul = false;
            } else {
                 resul = false;
            }
        }
        //comprobacion de NIEs
        //T
        else if (/^[T]{1}/.test(temp)) {
            if (temp[8] == /^[T]{1}[A-Z0-9]{8}$/.test(temp)) {
                return 3;
            } else if (temp[8] != /^[T]{1}[A-Z0-9]{8}$/.test(temp)) {
                var letra = String.fromCharCode(64 + n);
                var letranie = temp.charAt(8);
                if (letra != letranie) {
                    resul = false;
                } else {
                    resul = false;
                }
            }
        }
        //XYZ
        else if (/^[XYZ]{1}/.test(temp)) 
        {
            //var pos = str_replace(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['0','1','2'], temp).substring(0, 8) % 23;
            if (/^[X]{1}/.test(temp))
            {
                temp=temp.replace('X', '0');
            }
            else if (/^[Y]{1}/.test(temp))
            {
                temp=temp.replace('Y', '1');
            }
            else if (/^[Z]{1}/.test(temp))
            {
                temp=temp.replace('Z', '2');
            }

            var pos=temp.substring(0, 8) % 23;
            var letra = cadenadni.substring(pos, pos + 1);
            var letranie = temp.charAt(8);
            if (letranie == letra) 
            {
                resul = true;
            } 
            else if (letranie != letra)
            {
                resul = false;
            } else {
                resul = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return resul;
}
```