# validar un numero con javascrip

Tags: php, javascript

Nota: ya valide letra por letra y funcionabien,pero el problema es cuando el usuario pega el dato con numeros y letras
Solo debo recibir una cadena de 11 digitos,pero al poner una letra este pasa las validaciones que tengo, como lo soluciono?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

decidi hacer un parseo y validar que sea un numero pero se trunca el dato y si pasa como numerico[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui mi codigo

```
function buscarCuenta()
```

{

```
//alert("buscar cuenta");
id ="num_credito";

var valor = document.getElementById(id).value;
 var valor2=getCookie("num_credito");
    var n = valor.length;
    alert(valor);
if (valor.localeCompare(valor2)!=0)
{
    if(n==11)
     {    

        var a = parseInt(valor);
        alert(a);

         if(Number.isInteger(a)==false)
                  {
                    alert("No es un numero valido Verificar");
                    //document.getElementById(id).value = "";
                  }
                    if(Number.isInteger(a)==true)
                     {
                            setCookie("num_credito", valor);
                            putLoader();


                         var url="php/core.php";      
                        var values="Opcion=buscarTasa";
                        $.ajax({   
                            type: "POST",
                            url:url,
                            data:values,
                            success: function(datos){
                                $('#listaPendientes').html(datos);
                              }
                        });

                    //buscarCuenta();
                  }



    }//fin del if

}//fin 2 if

//  alert("Credito repetido");



}
```

Comment: revisa por favor si lo de este enlace te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70351/validacion-campo-input-text-solo-debe-aceptar-numeros-javascript

Answer (score 1):

En Javascript está la función `isNaN()`. Retorna `false` cuando la cadena sí es un número, caso contrario manda un `true`.

```
isNaN(123) //false
isNaN('Hello') //true
```

Esta función debiese servir:

```
function validateNumber(number)
{
    var res = {}
    res.error = false;
    res.message = "";
    if(number.length == 11 && isNaN(number) == false)
    {
        res.message = "Sin problemas";
        return res;
    }
    else
    {
        res.message = "Largo no permitido o contiene letras";
        res.error = true;
        return res;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar `e.preventDefault();`

Esto evita que se ejecute el codigo backend cuando se cumpla una condición.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { 
miformulario.codigo.addEventListener("keypress", soloNumeros, false); }); 
//Solo permite introducir numeros. function soloNumeros(e){ var key = 
window.event ? e.which : e.keyCode; if (key < 48 || key > 57) {  
.preventDefault(); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes de usar una expresión regular para validar que la cadena solo contenga los caracteres del 0 al 9 sin importar el orden en el cual se encuentren los numeros.

Lo cual lo puedes hacer cambiando:

```
var a = parseInt(valor);
if (Number.isInteger(a)==false)
```

Por:

```
var expresionRegularSoloNumeros = /^[0-9]+$/g;
if (expresionRegularSoloNumeros.test(valor) === false)
```

Answer (score 0):

yo tengo uno mas resumido 
HTML

```js
  //solo numeros 
  $('.input-number').on('input', function () { 
          this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
        });
//con letras y numeros 
 $('.form-control').on('input', function () { 
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.(),@ _-]/g,'');
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <input type='text' class='form-control input-number'
     id='coordenaday_mass' maxlength='45'   required='required' autofocus>
JAVASCRIPT
```

Comment: si lo desea con mas caracteres añadir lo siguiente  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g,'');