# ¿Como bloquear un input a solo numeros y asi como auto completar guiones en este (Aplicacion angular)?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, input

¿podrían ayudarme?.

Varan tengo este formulario

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" #f="ngForm"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="alert alert-danger mt-1 alert-dismissible" role="alert" *ngIf="ValidacionMessage">
                Por Favor verifique los campos marcados con *
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <!-- Nombre -->
            <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Nombre*</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input [disabled]="accion === 'view'" type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Nombre" [(ngModel)]="empresa.nombre" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Nombre -->

            <!-- Direccion -->
            <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Direccion*</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input [disabled]="accion === 'view'" type="text" name="direccion" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Direccion" [(ngModel)]="empresa.direccion" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Direccion -->

            <!-- Registro Fiscal -->
            <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Registro Fiscal*</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">

                    <input [disabled]="accion === 'view'" type="text" name="registro" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Registro" [(ngModel)]="empresa.registroFiscal" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Registro Fiscal -->

            <!-- Telefono -->
            <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Telefono*</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input [disabled]="accion === 'view'" type="text" name="telefono" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="telefono" [(ngModel)]="empresa.telefono">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Telefono -->

            <!-- Tamaño -->
            <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Tamaño*</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <select [disabled]="accion === 'view'" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="empresa.tamanoEmpresa_id"
                        name="tamano">
                        <option value="1">Pequeña</option>
                        <option value="2">Mediana</option>
                        <option value="3">Grande</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Tamaño-->

            <!-- NIT -->
            <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">NIT*</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input [disabled]="accion === 'view'" type="text" name="nit" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Numero de NIT" [(ngModel)]="empresa.nit">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--NIT -->

            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="form-group row mx-1" *ngIf=" accion !== 'view'">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Logo*</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input [disabled]="accion === 'view'" type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="logo"
                            [(ngModel)]="empresa.logo">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Elige un Logo</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Logo -->

            <!--Razon -->
            <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Razon Social*</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input [disabled]="accion === 'view'" type="text" name="razon" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Razon Social" [(ngModel)]="empresa.razonSocial">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Razon -->

            <!--Giro -->
            <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Giro*</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input [disabled]="accion === 'view'" type="text" name="giro" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Giro" [(ngModel)]="empresa.giro">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Giro -->


            <!--Email -->
            <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Email*</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input [disabled]="accion === 'view'" type="text" name="Email" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="empresa.email" email>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button *ngIf="accion === 'create'" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"
                    (click)="limpiar()">Limpiar</button>
                <button *ngIf="accion === 'create'" type="button" (click)="agregarEmpresa(f)" class="btn btn-primary"
                    name="guardar">Guardar</button>
                <button *ngIf="accion === 'editar'" type="button" (click)="editarEmpresa(f)" class="btn btn-primary"
                    name="Editar">Guardar Cambios</button>
                <button *ngIf="accion === 'view'" type="button" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()" class="btn btn-secondary"
                    name="Editar">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Y quisiera poder bloquear los campos registro fiscal, teléfono y nit a solamente números, me refiero a que no sea posible introducir letras ni otros caracteres, así mismo también quisiera poder auto completar un - en estos campos para ayudar al usuario, pero no realmente como hacerlo, he tratado poner type="number" pero me aparece al costado unos controles para subir y bajar números que tampoco se como quitarlos, ¿Me pueden brindar ayudar por favor?, no he encontrado como hacer esto utilizando Angular.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Validacion campo input text - Solo debe aceptar numeros - Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70351/validacion-campo-input-text-solo-debe-aceptar-numeros-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega esta función al input en un evento de KeyPress  (keypress)="validateFormat($event)"

```
validateFormat(event) {
    let key;
    if (event.type === 'paste') {
      key = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    } else {
      key = event.keyCode;
      key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    }
    const regex = /[0-9]|\./;
     if (!regex.test(key)) {
      event.returnValue = false;
       if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault();
       }
     }
    }
```

el input te quedaria de esta manera

```
   <input
    [(ngModel)]="code"
    id="code"
    name="code"
    (keypress)="validateFormat($event)"
  />
```